# Module parse failed when I use my customized loader

Tags: vue.js, webpack, vuejs2, vue-loader

I am trying to learn to write a loader in vue2 project.
And I want to use this loader to add some attributes in some tag automatically before processing to vue-loader.

The code of my loader is:

```js
module.exports = function (content) {
  const templateMatch = content.match(/<template>([\s\S]*?)<\/template>/);
  let restContent = content
  if (templateMatch) {
    const templateContent = templateMatch[1];
    restContent = content.replace(/<template>[\s\S]*?<\/template>/, '');
    
    let returnContent = templateContent.replace(/<\/el-/g, '\n</el-')
    returnContent = returnContent.replace(/<el-/g, '\n<el-')
    returnContent = returnContent.replace(/<input/g, '\n<input')

    var regInput = /<(input)([^<>]*)>/g // tmp
    let contentArr = returnContent.split('\n')
    let resultArr = contentArr.map((item, index) => {
      if (regInput.test(item)) {
        item = item.replace(/<input/g, '<input name="input_name"')
      }
      return item
    })
    const result = resultArr.join('\n')
    console.log('result', result)
    return `module.exports = ${JSON.stringify(result + restContent)};`
  } else {
    return `module.exports = ${JSON.stringify(content)};`
  }
}
```

And I use it in vue.config.js:

```js
module.exports = defineConfig({
  transpileDependencies: true,
  chainWebpack: config => {
   
    config.module
      .rule('vue')
      .test(/\.vue$/)
      .use('vue-loader')
      .loader('vue-loader')
      .end()
      .use('my-loader')
      .loader(path.resolve(__dirname, './my-loader.js'))
      .end()
  }
})
```

After run *pnpm serve* command, I meet a error that shows:

```text
> 1 | \n#app {\n  font-family: Avenir, Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif;\n  -webkit-font-smoothing: antialiased;\n  -moz-osx-font-smoothing: grayscale;\n  text-align: center;\n  color: #2c3e50;\n  margin-top: 60px;\n}\n
    |        
ERROR in ./src/App.vue?vue&type=script&lang=js
```

From console log I can see that the attribute has been added into the input tag

result

```html
<div id="app">
    
<el-input v-model="input" placeholder="please input">
</el-input>
    
<input name="input_name" v-model="input2" placeholder="please input" />
    <img alt="Vue logo" src="./assets/logo.png">
    <HelloWorld msg="Welcome to Your Vue.js App"/>
  </div>
```

But I have no idea why it parse failed finally.

I have upload the project code to [github](https://github.com/zkch/custom-loader)
Thank you for your answer sincerely.